# Javascript flow in creating DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

If I insert some element into DOM tree

```
document.getElementById("settings-details-form").innerHTML = "<h2 id=\"ddd\">hello</h2>";
```

will the next line of JS code be executed before the DOM updates with the new element ?

What is the JavaScript execution model when doing DOM updates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the next line is executed

- **the DOM has been updated**, you may for example query the dimensions of the element you add
- **the window hasn't been rendered** which means you don't have to worry about the user seeing an incomplete state : the window will be rendered when your code ends

Note that most browsers do optimizations : if you don't query the dimensions, for example, they won't be computed until they're needed (for the window rendering, ultimately). That's why it's faster to do a bunch of DOM changes when you don't query the DOM layout in the middle so that the reflow is computed only once (see [Mozilla notes on HTML Reflow](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html)). The exact flow is highly browser engine dependent but functionally, whatever the browser, the next line of code will see an updated DOM.